# Nissan door does not open from outside

Tags: nissan, door

I've had a broken outer door handle for the driver door of my Nissan Teana 2007 model. I replaced it but the mechanic who was working on it broke another thing and he didnt seem to know how to fix it.

This is for the driver door (right side in NZ).

The problem is, when I am inside the car and open the door using the inside door handle, it opens normally, but, when I lock the car using the remote and unlock it, it doesnt open from the outside anymore, although the lock button is on the "unlocked" position from the inside. If I open the inside door handle, even if I dont go all the way to open the door from the inside, just half way through, I can hear a click in the door near the locking mechanisim and then I can open it using the outer door handle. Afterwards, unless I lock the door again, I can use the outer door handle.

Any idea what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

You've got a broken or dislodged linkage in the lock mechanism. If you remove the door card (the interior door trim), you should be able to get at it, and reconnect or replace it.